# Issue with hover on elements populated by ajax load or get function

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, get, hover

I'm having an issue with hover function in FF and Chrome. I've a table that's populated dynamically through ajax. I'm then trying to manipulate the elements sends through ajax, but it's not working in FF and Chrome. Here is the code of the page:

```
/** My page**/
$('#resourcelist tbody').load(inc_processplugin.asp?cmd=select&tc=listresource,function () {
             $('#divShowAddResource').hide();
      });

 $('.editable')
        .hover(function () {
            //alert('Am hovering');
            //change background of an editable element if mouse hover
            $(this).toggleClass('over-inline');
        })


/** The elements editable is the one that populate the tbody above. It's generated dynamically from inc_processplugin.asp Here is part of the incprocessplugin.asp that populate the tbody element**/

query = "SELECT * from t_cmsix_tc_resource WHERE isnull(resource_inactive,0)=0"
        objRs.Open query, objConn   
         Do while Not objRs.EOF     
            Response.Write("<tr>" & vbCrlf)          
            Response.Write("<td><span class=""editable"" id=""" & objRs("resource_id")  & """>" & objRs("resource_name") & "</span></td>" & vbCrlf) 
            Response.Write("</tr>" & vbCrlf) 
            objRs.MoveNext    
         Loop `
```

The tbody element is correctly populated but the hover or any other actions on the .editable elements that are generated dynamically is not working.

Any help please????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use $.fn.live()

http://api.jquery.com/live/

> Description: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Update
It should also be noted that another appropriate solution is:

```
$.fn.delegate()
```

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

> Description: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

Comment: Ok I'll try with the live function and getback to you.

Comment: Thankksssssss bstakes...The live function save my day.Cheers

Comment: live() is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. You should use on() instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your hover is set before ajax is done loading. Try putting the .hover() function in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: $(document).ready is not connected to ajax and will not wait for any ajax calls before firing. It has caused me many headaches

Comment: hi Jason, of course I've put the document.ready function. This is just a sample of the code. It begins with 
    $(document).ready(function () {....

Answer (score 0):

After any ajax call you have to re-call the hover function on the elements

```
    $('#resourcelist tbody').load(inc_processplugin.asp?cmd=select&tc=listresource,function () {
         $('#divShowAddResource').hide();
         $('.editable').hover(function () {
             $(this).toggleClass('over-inline');
         })
    })

  });
```

Comment: Hi Johny,Your solution too has worked but since I've many type of editable, i'll need to repeat the code in each load.
I've used live function to attach the hover and it's working fine.

Comment: So I've found the solution.
I've used the live function to attached the hover handler.

    $('#resourcelist tbody').load(inc_processplugin.asp?cmd=select&tc=listresource,function () {
             $('#divShowAddResource').hide();
      });

    $('.editable').live({
        hover : function () {
            //alert('Am hovering');
            //change background of an editable element if mouse hover
            $(this).toggleClass('over-inline');
        },
       click: function(){
   //my click stuffs are put here and they work fine
    )});

Thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try running your jQuery code in the $(document).ready() event handler. Those td elements may not exist when you're attaching the hover event handler, and therefore it's not working.

you can also run the hover code in the ajax success handler, after you're sure that the elements have been created

Comment: The jquery code is running the $(document).ready(). I've just shared a sample of the code. So that couldnot be the source of the problem. I should also add that on IE7, the hover is working after a refresh of the page, following the first load of the page.